# class design in a little java, a little pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, computer-science

I am reading [A Little Java, A Few Patterns](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-java-few-patterns) recently, Chapter 3 introduce `Pizza` class and some its subclasses. It looks strange to me that `Crust`, `Cheese` and `Olive` class are defined as subclass of `Pizza`

Apparently, those are ingredients of a pizza, and the relation between those ingredients and a pizza is `has a` not `is a`.

So why those ingredients class are defined as subclass of `Pizza` ?

FYI, code snippet below is the class structure used in this book.
[image]

Comment: We can't see the text in question, so we can only guess. I suspect that you misinterpreted what the text says; if you didn't, then the text is wrong. None of those are subclasses of Pizza.

Comment: Along the lines what @chrylis said, the Amazon.com reviews for this book are controversial. There are plenty of better books to spend your time on.

Answer (score 1):

They sound like they might be described as **types** of `Pizza`; which would make it a **is-a** relationship (a *mushroom pizza* is a *pizza*).

Comment: I don't think it's this case. I have uploaded the class structure, it would be better if you have a look at this book and answer this quesiton

Comment: @JiacaiLiu The text is describing a generic `Pizza` type, and sub-classes which are concrete implementations. `Pizza<T>` and `Olive<T> extends Pizza<T>`, the `Pizza` is a `Collection` (specifically, the author is trying to explain [generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) with a [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)).

Comment: I still couldn't figure it out, In `Cheese` and other subclasses, why there is a `Pizza` field, is this a variant of  builder pattern ?

Comment: Each pizza can contain multiple other "pizzas". It's really a `Collection`; the `Builder` is merely the strategy used to create the final `Pizza` reference.

Comment: There's really no sensible way to understand `class Crust extends Pizza.`

Comment: `Pizza` is a collection ?  I don't think so for `Pizza` field is defined only in subclass, and meanwhile `Crust` extends `Pizza` but have no `Pizza` field, which is different to others, how should this happen ?

Comment: Again, the `Builder` may well start with `Crust` and add `Cheese`.

Comment: Well, I don't know whether or not you have read the book, Chapter 3 doesn't tell about object creation,  and I can hardly recognize `Pizza` and its subclasses as demo for `Builder` pattern.

Comment: @JiacaiLiu Crust is not a Pizza (it's part of a pizza). Inheritance is misused. The design does not respect the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). This book is from 1998. After the popular GoF book, several "Patterns" books came out to ride that wave. Many were/are a waste of time, in my opinion. I recommend Head First Design Patterns if you want something worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

The names of the subclasses are somewhat misleading. `Sausage`, for instance, isn't a topping; it's a pizza topped with sausage, and the same goes for `Cheese`, `Olive`, and `Anchovy`. `Crust` is really a pizza without any toppings. Thinking about pizzas this way allows for an easy recursive description:

- A plain crust is a pizza.
- If you take a pizza and add cheese on top, the result is a pizza.
- If you take a pizza and add sausage on top, the result is a pizza.
- If you take a pizza and add anchovies on top, the result is a pizza.
- If you take a pizza and add olives on top, the result is a pizza.

`Crust` is the base case of the recursion, and the 'toppings' make recursive calls to `Pizza`. That's why the 'toppings' have a `Pizza` field: the subclass tells you what the topmost layer of the resulting pizza is, and the field tells you what the lower layers are.

This also makes it easy to define methods recursively. Say we want to check whether a pizza is vegetarian:

- If the pizza is a plain crust, then there isn't any meat, and so the pizza is vegetarian. (Base case: true)
- Otherwise, the pizza consists of a top layer and a sub-pizza.
- Check the top layer first. If the top layer is sausage or anchovies, then the pizza isn't vegetarian. (Base case: false)
- Otherwise, the top layer is cheese or olives. In that case, the pizza is vegetarian if and only the sub-pizza underneath the top layer is.
- Check whether the sub-pizza is vegetarian. (Recursion)

If the names really bother you, you can rename `Crust` as `PizzaWithNoToppings`, `Sausage` as `PizzaToppedWithSausage`, and so on. These names are pretty ugly though, and don't fit at all in a stylistic book like *A Little Java*.

Answer (score 1):

Though the book's title contains Java, it's not a book about Java. Under the surface, it's teaching functional programming using Java.

This is the key to understanding those examples. For exmaple, the first chapter is really about Union datatype (or sum datatype) you would normally find in functional programming languages such as ML.

In this book, it doesn't use any collection concepts like set, map, or list. Instead, the author teaches you to create those concepts.

If you are familiar with list type in haskell or SML, those definitions should be quite natural.

Answer (score 0):

Jiacai Liu, I don't know the book, but your doubts are reasonable. In well written OOP code Pizza should be an object with a set of ingredients. And each class that in example extends Pizza should implement Ingredient interface:

```
class Pizza {
  private Set<Ingredient> ingredients;
  //code
}

interface Ingredient {}

class Crust implements Ingredient {}
class Cheese implements Ingredient {}
class Olive implements Ingredient {}
```